# How to convert a string[] to an EventEmitter string[] in angular 4 using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

> Language: Javascript- saved as .ts files,  typescript
>
> Framework: Angular 4

I'm trying to write an application which adds chips (tags in Angular 1) when I type in the input box and hit Add Chip.

My issue is that I have two variables, addSelectedCode and addCode, defined as the following:

```
@Input() addSelectedCode: string[];

@Output() addCode: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter;
```

whenever I try to set one equal to the other, I get an error.

```
this.addCode = this.addSelectedCode;
```

Following is the error:

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to EventEmitter 'string[]'. Property __isAsync is missing in string[].

I am not sure how to resolve this error.Can anyone shed light on a solution?

RESOLVED: Answer in Code: this.addCode.emit(this.selectedCode);

Comment: This line `this.addCode = this.addSelectedCode;` doesn't make any sense. What's it's purpose? If you want to use them for 2-way binding, then just ensure they have the right name `@Input() addSelectedCode:string[];` and `@Output() addSelectedCodeChange:EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter<string[]>();` (same names, just with added `Change` for the output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your template in your parent that calls the component that has the @Input and @Output statements above, should have a line such as `<child-component [addselectedCode]="varOfThisParentContainingStringArray" (addCode)="methodInThisParentComponentReciveingStringArray($event)></child-component>`

Then in the Parent component you need a method:

```
methodInThisParentComponentRecievingStringArray(evnt: string[]): void {...}
```

to receive it...

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to emit an event with the new array, then you will need:

```
@Output() addCode = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
...

onAdd(code) {
 this.addSelectedCode.push(code);
 this.addCode.emit(this.addSelectedCode);
}
```

but you may not need it, `addSelectedCode` will be a live value visible to the callee (2-way bound).